# J2ME text encryption - javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException

Tags: java, encryption, java-me, midp

I use **DES** algorithm to encrypt/decrypt my text. And it works perfect with latin texts.

But when I start encrypt/decrypt cyrillic text, decrypted one is shown as *????? ????????* in my `TextField` form and in console. How can i fix it?

After [Joachim Sauer advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896206/839601) I changed `inputBytes = textToEnrypt.getBytes();` to `inputBytes = textToEnrypt.getBytes("UTF-8");` and now I have *javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException*. Help me, please...

```
package crypting;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

public class Encryptor extends MIDlet {

    String buffer;

    public void startApp() {
        String keyString = "testtest";
//        encrypt("Text for encrypting", keyString);
        encrypt("Привет", keyString);
        decrypt(buffer, keyString);
    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }

    public void encrypt(String textToEnrypt, String keyString) {
        Cipher cipher;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            return;
        }

        byte[] keyData = keyString.getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyData, 0, keyData.length, "DES");

        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            return;
        }

        int cypheredBytes = 0;

        byte[] inputBytes;
        try {
            inputBytes = textToEnrypt.getBytes("UTF-8");
//            inputBytes = textToEnrypt.getBytes();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            return;
        }

        byte[] outputBytes = new byte[100];

        try {
            cypheredBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.length,
                    outputBytes, 0);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            return;
        }

        String str = new String(outputBytes, 0, cypheredBytes);
        buffer = str;
        System.out.println("Encrypted string = " + str);
    }


    public void decrypt(String textToDecrypt, String keyString) {
        Cipher cipher;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            return;
        }

        byte[] keyData = keyString.getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyData, 0, keyData.length, "DES");

        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("2. " + ex.toString());
            return;
        }

        int cypheredBytes = 0;

        byte[] inputBytes;
        try {
            inputBytes = textToDecrypt.getBytes("UTF-8");
//            inputBytes = textToDecrypt.getBytes();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("3. " + ex.toString());
            return;
        }

        byte[] outputBytes = new byte[100];

        try {
            cypheredBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.length,
                    outputBytes, 0);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("4. " + ex.toString());
            return;
        }

        String str = new String(outputBytes, 0, cypheredBytes);
        System.out.println("Decrypted string = " + str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make it work with the following changes.

Change the return type of **encrypt** method, from `void` to `byte[]`:

```
static public byte[] encrypt(String textToEnrypt, String keyString)
  throws Exception
{
    //at the end
    //write this down:
    byte[] newResponse = new byte[cypheredBytes];
    for(int i=0;i &lt; cypheredBytes;i++)
    {
        newResponse[i] = outputBytes[i];
    }
    return newResponse;
}
```

Instead of:

```
String str = new String(outputBytes, 0, cypheredBytes);
buffer = str;
System.out.println("Encrypted string = " + str);
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess (and I can't do more without you showing some code) is that you're using `getBytes()` without a parameter and construct the `String` from the `byte[]` without a parameter as well. That means using the platform default encoding and if that can't represent cyrillic characters, then that's what you get.

It's better to use UTF-8 for both transformations, this way you can represent every Unicode character.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But now I have another problem - javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException. I described it in the topic.

Answer (score 2):

DES uses a 64-bit (8-byte) block size. You have to make sure that the data you're encrypting is a multiple of 8 bytes, i.e. pad it out with zero bytes or whatever to ensure that it is. Otherwise you'll get an IllegalBlockSizeException. You'll need to do this after you convert the string to UTF-8, of course....

Answer (score 1):

One problem is the line

```
String str = new String(outputBytes, 0, cypheredBytes);
```

in your encrypt method. You cannot use `String` as a container for binary data. Encrypted data should not be converted to a String unless it is a requirement, and then you need to use an appropriate codec such as base64.